# How to simply handle a factory of multiple parameter-diverging classes with Guice?

Tags: java, guice, factory

I have the following very simple interface:

```java
public interface IDataSource<T> {
    Observable<T> observable();
}
```

Now I'll be having multiple implementations of it. Each of those implementation may rely on varying parameters (different storage objects: JDBC, Cassandra, Redis...). So for instance I'll have:

```java
public class CassandraDataSource implements IDataSource<MyCassandraObject> {
    @Inject
    public CassandraDataSource(Keyspace ks) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class OtherCassandraDataSource implements IDataSource<MyOtherCassandraObject> {
    @Inject
    public OtherCassandraDataSource(Keyspace ks) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class JDBCDataSource implements IDataSource<MyJdbcObject> {
    @Inject
    public JDBCDataSource(Database db) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And so on.

What I would like is to reference each of those with a string so that i can call a factory which would return the appropriate `IDataSource`. Something that would behave like that:

```java
public class DataSourceFactory {
    public static final Map<String, Supplier<IDataSource<?>>>   map = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> IDataSource<T> get(String ref) {
        return (IDataSource<T>) map.get(ref).get();
    }
}
```

I could be giving N `Providers`as parameters (or direct field injection) to my factory (N being the number of `IDataSource` I use) and map strings to those in the constructor or use a switch in the `get` method but this would become quite a mess once I reach 10 to 20 `IDataSource` (or more!)

Is there some simpler solution I've been overlooking ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have a factory, then no—[as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25226912/1426891) a manual factory is probably the best you can get.

However, if you bind all of your IDataSource implementations to IDataSource with different binding annotations, then you might be able to skip the factory and simply inject `@Source("foo") IDataSource` and get back the instance you want. The configuration between String and implementation still has to live somewhere, but you can have it live in a Guice module if you'd like. And, by injecting the Injector and supplying a compatible annotation implementation, you can even write a factory like DataSourceFactory that defers to Guice.

As a side note, beware of your DataSourceFactory; `get` will have no safe way to supply a value for its type parameter T.